# ViewController orientation on external monitor

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8

I have an iPad kiosk app that displays video on an external monitor connected via an HDMI cable. The device orientation is set to Landscape Left or Landscape Right in the apps general settings. I want the app to be displayed in landscape on the iPad and on the external monitor. When I run the app in iOS7 the external monitors view controller is displayed correctly in landscape orientation, but when run under iOS 8 the external monitor's view controller is rotated 90 degrees counterclockwise, into portrait orientation.

How do I force the external monitor to the correct landscape orientation? What has changed between iOS 7 and 8 to cause this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had a similar issue with a landscape-only iPad app that supports airplay. On the iPad screen, everything was working fine, but on the external display, starting @ iOS 8.0, orientation issues started happening. I tried many things, what ended up helping was these two fixes:

On the `shouldAutorotate` method of your ViewController, return `NO`.

Implement the `application:supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:` method:

```
    - (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)_window
    {
        if ([UIScreen mainScreen] == _window.screen || !_window)
        {
            return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
        }
        else
        {
            return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
        }
    }
```

The second part of the fix may require some changes on your side, since you're not using AirPlay, but I hope it can help lead you to the right solution. Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks, Chonch. This worked for me as well. I don't quite get WHY it is working, but now my external monitor is displaying correctly in landscape orientation for both iOS 7 & 8.

Comment: I'm very glad to hear that. I remember how frustrating it was when I was dealing with this issue... :-)